# Returning RegExp Patterns from a JSON file to Create Angular Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, promise

I'm sure there's a better way to do this but I can't figure it out....

I created a JSON file with an array of field objects. I'm returning the data using a promise and attempting to a to create custom directives in Angular.

I'm unable to store complex patterns like the example below in my JSON file.  Essentially I have no idea how to save various patterns similar to the one below and add it to a directive....

```
^(?:(?:\(?(?:00|\+)([1-4]\d\d|[1-9]\d?)\)?)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?)?((?:\(?\d{1,}\)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?){0,})(?:[\-\.\ \\\/]?(?:#|ext\.?|extension|x)[\-\.\ \\\/]?(\d+))?$
```

Random Example below - how to get JSON Data > an Angular Directive......?

```
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "label": "Full Name",
            "type": "text",
            "pattern": "......."
        },
        {
            "label": "Email",
            "type": "email",
            "pattern": "..............."
        },
        {
            "label": "Phone",
            "type": "text",
            "pattern": "................."
        }
    ]
}




(function() {
angular.module('directives', [])
    .directive('regexp', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'data/regexp.html'
            etc......
        };
    })

}());
```

Comment: What does this have to do with promises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store regex objects in JSON, so you will need to put the pattern in a JSON string. For that, you will need to escape all backslashes and quotes. The simplest way to go for that is to use

```
JSON.stringify(/pattern/.source)
```

which in your case will end up with

```
{
    "label": "Full Name",
    "type": "text",
    "pattern": "^(?:(?:\\(?(?:00|\\+)([1-4]\\d\\d|[1-9]\\d?)\\)?)?[\\-\\.\\ \\\\\\/]?)?((?:\\(?\\d{1,}\\)?[\\-\\.\\ \\\\\\/]?){0,})(?:[\\-\\.\\ \\\\\\/]?(?:#|ext\\.?|extension|x)[\\-\\.\\ \\\\\\/]?(\\d+))?$"
}
```

You can then pass that string (after you `JSON.parse`d the response) to [`new RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to get back a regular expression that you can match with.